# Exception to json - JavaME

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am writing a program for blackberry in java me.

Is there anyway I can write java exception caught into a json format? How can I do that? What are the things I should consider? Thanks!

Will it be like this...

```
catch (IOException e) {
    String IOExceptionMsg = 
        "description:Warn exception: OSError. Exc_type: :Caught IOException:" + 
        e.toString() + ",filename: " + imageName;

    out.write(IOExceptionMsg.getBytes())
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    String Exception = 
        "description: Unknown Error:Caught Exception:" + e.toString() + 
        ",filename:" + imageName;

        out.write(Exception.getBytes());
        out.flush();
}
```

I have a json format like this..How do I place them together?

```
`public String toJSON()
{
final String 
IMAGENAME = imageName,
description = "",
filename = imageName;
JSONObject outer = new JSONObject();
JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
try {
outer.put(IMAGENAME, inner);

// Values are added to the JSONObject in pairs, label then value
inner.put(description, description);
inner.put(filename, imageName);
} catch (JSONException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
return outer.toString();
        }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can write java exception caught into a json format?

You can catch exception then you can extract its message and put it into JSON to perform something you need you can't tell JVM directly to throw it in JSON trace .

> What about if I have three different types of exceptions? How do I match the filename and the exception?

```
try{
  //something
}catch(MyExceptionOne ex){
  //do something
}catch(MyExceptionTwo ex){
  //do something different
}catch(MyExceptionThree ex){
  //do something very different
}
```

Comment: What about if I have three different types of exceptions? How do I match the filename and the exception?

Comment: The code above is not in json format. How can I throw it in JSON trace?

Comment: do you want to catch JSONException or want to take trace in JSON format ?

Comment: then simply take the trace in normal format and create JSON from it